# How to calculate and set the height for an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have one parent div and three child divs as so

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">...</div>
    <div id="child2">...</div>
    <div id="child3">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to calculate and set the height of `child3` based on this pseudo formula

`child3height = parentheight - child1height + child2height`

How can I write this in jQuery and set it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get the height of parent by $('#parent').height and childs with $('#child1').height() and apply a simple mathamatics rule and get height in a variable.

```
var child3Height = $('#parent').height - ($('#child1').height() + $('#child2').height());
```

and then store that variable in child3 with .height() property of jquery

```
$('#child3').height(child3Height);
```

Comment: I tried this but the div that I'm trying to set the height to keeps getting the wrong height. Also, a lot of my dimensions are appearing with decimal values. Why is that? Is it because I'm using em as my unit for padding/margin or width/height?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#child3').height($('#parent').height()-$('#child1').height()+$('#child2').height())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parentheight = $("#parent").height();
var child1height = $("#child1").height();
var child2height = $("#child2").height();

$("#child3").height(parentheight - child1height + child2height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var child3Height = $('#parent').height() - $('#child1').height() + $('#child2').height();
$('#child3').height(child3Height);
$('span').html('Child3 height is ' + child3Height); //this line only for demo purpose
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">...</div>
  <div id="child2">...</div>
  <div id="child3">...</div>
</div>

<span></span> <!--demo purpose only-->
```